# Database - have 2 Tables and need another one which has both IDs and another field

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring, hibernate

i use spring and hibernate.

Ok so in my programm i have articles and stores (entities), which are stored in a myql database. i now need a way to store the amount of articles in each store in the database.

the store table only includes the store names. 
the article table includes the articleID and more information about the article.

i thought about something like a amount-table which has: 
articleID - storename - amount

how can i implement this?

it would be perfect if the table is also always uptodate. that means, if i add a article or store, the amount-table entities for that article are generated automaticly...

is that possible?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add one more column in your articles table with storeid.
Then then can join those two table on based on store ids then insert the same into ur new table with additional details also.